# Field of "CustomType" Not working properly in Experience Editor

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, sitecore-api

I have a date field which is "CustomType". It has validation in the 'Validation' field with this Regex  ^(?!\s*$).+
I need to edit this field in Item through Experience Editor.

I have created a CustomExperienceEditorButton and added the field. Then tagged the custom button in a Rendering.

When I open the page in Experience Editor Mode and click on the Custom Button the field is Coming.

If I edit the field and click ok for the first time it works fine and is not able to save the field's value. But once it gets the validation error if I am not giving the correct value then it constantly shows the validation error message.

So it seems as soon it gets the validation error it is storing it somewhere. Is there a way I can reset the validation for the field in sitecore.context, so that when the field is updated the error message does not repeat?